# How to get city related area in country in GeoNames Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql

I am using GeoNames database which is showing State in ADM1 section and City ADM2 but when i use ADM2 city related filter in query area I am not getting.

```
SELECT * FROM `saudi` WHERE feature_code='ADM1';
```

[image: State Administration]

```
SELECT * FROM `saudi` WHERE feature_code='ADM2' and admin1_code='14';
```

[image: City Administration]

For City dependency area using this query I am not getting any things

```
SELECT * FROM `saudi` WHERE feature_code like 'PPL%' and admin1_code='14' and admin2_code='10972361'
```

[image: Area & locality]

For area if i use this query

```
SELECT * FROM `saudi` WHERE feature_code like 'PPL%' and admin1_code='14';
```

I am getting all the area of that State/Region but this is wrong actually that area/locality should be come based on city selection

Comment: I think you just do not have in your DB rows where feature_code started with 'PPL' and admin2_code equal to 10972361.

Comment: @fifonik

No actually , when i download SA.zip from GeoNames database. There is only this much data, do you know where i can get complete data for admin2code city related areas..